# como podria reutilizar este codigo para insertar datos en dos tablas diferentes

Tags: java, mysql

tengo dos tablas con los mismos campos y estoy utilizando dos metodos iguales para cada insert en cada tabla lo unico que cambia es el nombre de la tabla. quisiera reutilizar el codigo solo cambiando el nombre de la tabla mediante un combobox.  hay alguna foma?

```
 public int insertarHerra(String nombreHerra, String descripcionHerra, int stockHerra, String fechaAdquisicion) {
    conectando = Conectar.getConnection();
    //System.out.println(nombre);
    try {
        String sql = "insert into herramientasalmacen(nombreHerra, descripcionHerra, stockHerra,fechaAdquisicion) values(?,?,?,?)";
        preparando = conectando.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparando.setString(1, nombreHerra);
        preparando.setString(2, descripcionHerra);
        preparando.setInt(3, stockHerra);
        preparando.setString(4, fechaAdquisicion);

        int dato = preparando.executeUpdate();
        return dato;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error al registrar usuario.");
    }
    return 0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////INSERTAR CONSUMIBLES////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public int insertarConsu(String nombreConsu, String descripcionConsu, int stockConsu, String fechaAdquisicion) {
    conectando = Conectar.getConnection();
    //System.out.println(nombre);
    try {
        String sql = "insert into consumiblesalmacen(nombreConsu, descripcionConsu, stockConsu,fechaAdquisicion) values(?,?,?,?)";
        preparando = conectando.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparando.setString(1, nombreConsu);
        preparando.setString(2, descripcionConsu);
        preparando.setInt(3, stockConsu);
        preparando.setString(4, fechaAdquisicion);

        int dato = preparando.executeUpdate();
        return dato;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error al registrar usuario.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para responder especificamente tu pregunta, podrías agregar un parámetro al método que indique en que tabla se debe hacer el INSERT.

```
public int insertarHerraOConsu(String tabla, String nombre, String descripcion, int stock, String fechaAdquisicion) {
        conectando = Conectar.getConnection();

        try {
            String sql = "insert into " + tabla + "(nombreHerra, descripcionHerra, stockHerra,fechaAdquisicion) values(?,?,?,?)";
            preparando = conectando.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparando.setString(1, nombreHerra);
            preparando.setString(2, descripcionHerra);
            preparando.setInt(3, stockHerra);
            preparando.setString(4, fechaAdquisicion);

            int dato = preparando.executeUpdate();
            return dato;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error al registrar usuario.");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Si usas esta solución, debes tener cuidado de lo que selecciona el usuario en el combo no sea lo mismo que le pases al metodo, pues te podrían hacer inyección de SQL. En este caso, lo conveniente es que utilices constantes para la selección del usuario y tu lo valides y transformes al nombre de la tabla.

Ahora bien, tal vez puedes ser más conveniente que utilices una única tabla y agregues una columna indicando el tipo: herramienta o consumible.

Saludos